# Is it possible to specify one @Component class in context config so it's dependencies would be resolved automatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I want to perform an integration test of single service in my Spring Boot application. So I would like to only have this service and it's dependencies to be added into test application context.

Suppose I have two classes in different packages `A` and `B` (`A` has a reference on `B`) marked with `@Component` annotation. When I run the application, `@SpringBootApplication` finds all my beans and adds them to the context with implicit `@ComponentScan`.

In my test configuration I would like to specify only one class `A` and make Spring Boot to resolve it's dependencies (`B`) and add it to the context.

Is it possible with Spring Boot 2 or the most suitable option for me would to create a separate `@Configuration` with required classes declared explicitly? (actually there are more than 2, that's why I am asking)

Comment: The problem is that the point of dependency injection is that `A` doesn't necessarily know what implementation of `B` it will get, so there's no way for Spring to transitively import `@Component` beans. I always go with separate test `@Configuration` classes (and a lot of the time, if you use constructor injection you can eliminate the need for Spring altogether).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my test configuration I would like to specify only one class `A` and make Spring Boot to resolve it's dependencies (`B`) and add it to the context.

No, that's unfortunately not possible since Spring would not know how to locate the dependencies and/or which concrete types you actually want.

> Is it possible with Spring Boot 2 or the most suitable option for me would to create a separate `@Configuration` with required classes declared explicitly?

Yes, you can declare a dedicated test `@Configuration` class solely for that purpose; however, you may find it more beneficial to simply reuse a *common* set of configuration classes across your test classes in order to benefit from the context caching support in the *Spring TestContext Framework*.

Comment: Used TestContainers for Postrgres and common configuration for context caching, also disabled some beans with @Conditional and profiles, thank you :)